# Get proccess by name of displayNameFile

Tags: c#, windows, process, system.diagnostics

Hello I have an application that shows all the installed apps that you have in the pc, for example:

google chrome
Mozilla Firefox 63.0.3(x64 en-GB)
etc...

I want to get the process of each app by name.
(like that Mozilla Firefox 63.0.3(x64 en-GB).getProcess())

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You want to enumerate all running processes, and discover each ones executable filename?

Comment: I want to know what are the process of app by the displayName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could begin by building a dictionary of process using WMI and FileVersionInfo.

```
private static IList<ProcessInfo> BuildProcessDictionary()
{
  var wmiQueryString = "SELECT ProcessId, ExecutablePath FROM Win32_Process";
  using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQueryString))
  using (var results = searcher.Get())
  {
    var processList = from p in Process.GetProcesses()
                      join mo in results.Cast<ManagementObject>()
                      on p.Id equals (int)(uint)mo["ProcessId"]
                      select new ProcessInfo
                      {
                        Process = p,
                        Path = (string)mo["ExecutablePath"],
                        DisplayName = (string)mo["ExecutablePath"]!=null?FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo((string)mo["ExecutablePath"]).FileDescription:string.Empty
                      };
                return processList.ToList();
   }
   return default;
 }

 public class ProcessInfo
 {
   public string Path { get; set; }
   public string DisplayName { get; set; }
   public Process Process { get; set; }
 }
```

Then you can query the collection

```
var processDictionary = BuildProcessDictionary();
var found = processDictionary.Where(x => x.DisplayName!=null && x.DisplayName.Equals("Google Chrome"));
```

**Update**

```
var listOfPrograms = new[] { "Google Chrome", "Notepad" };
var processDictionary = BuildProcessDictionary();
foreach (var item in listOfPrograms)
{
  try
  {
    var programInstances = processDictionary.Where(x => x.DisplayName != null && x.DisplayName.Equals(item));
    foreach (var programInstance in programInstances)
    {
      programInstance.Process.Kill();
    }
  }
  catch (Exception )
  {
     // Log items that wasn't found or coudn't be killed.
    Console.WriteLine($"Could not find or kill process {item}");
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks you really helped me but I need something diffrenet
I have a list of "chosen apps" like mozilla firefox and I want to find and kill them
Could you try to help me ?

Comment: @Dr.Memory Sorry for delayed response,  I have updated my Answer based on your comments. A List Of Programs would be compared with the items in the dictionary, and if a matching is found (which means it is running), it would kill it.

Comment: Thank you very much but can u explain me why the code doesnt compile here:


                      select new ProcessInfo
                      {
                        Process = p,
                        Path = (string)mo["ExecutablePath"],
                        DisplayName = (string)mo["ExecutablePath"]!=null?FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo((string)mo["ExecutablePath"]).FileDescription:string.Empty
                      };

Comment: Hope you have reference to System.Diagnostics and System.Management ? if not, please add them

Comment: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'C:\Windows\System32\RuntimeBroker.exe'

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of all processes:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...
Process[] allProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
```

and then for each process you can find the information (ex. file name, module name,...) about the [`ProccessModule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processmodule?view=netframework-4.7.2) that was used to start the process with the [`Process.MainModule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainmodule?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Process_MainModule) property.

Comment: I am sorry but I want specific apps not all the process